# Parsing and Writing Files in PHP

Tags: php, file-io

I'm attempting to open a directory full of text files, and then read each file line-by-line, writing the information in each line to a new file.  Within each text file in the directory I'm trying to iterate, the information is formed like:

```
JunkInfo/UserName_ID_Date_Location.Type
```

So I want to open every one of those text files and write a line to my new file in the form of:

```
UserName,ID,Date,Location,Type
```

Here's the code I've come up with so far:

```
<?php

$my_file = 'info.txt';
$writeFile = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file

$files = scandir('/../DirectoryToScan');
foreach($files as $file)
{
    $handle = @fopen($file, "r");
    if ($handle) 
    {
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) 
        {
            $data = explode("_", $buffer);
            $username = explode("/", $data[0])[1];
            $location = explode(".", $data[3])[0];
            $type = explode(".", $data[3])[1];

            $stringToWrite = $username . "," . $data[1] . "," . $data[2] . "," . $location . "," . $type;

            fwrite($writeFile, $stringToWrite);
        }

        if (!feof($handle)) 
        {
             echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

fclose($writeFile);
?>
```

So my problem is, this doesn't seem to work. I just never get anything happening -- the output file is never written and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Does the `$files` array contain what you think it does? Try a `print_r($files)` before your `foreach` loop to see what's in it.

Comment: Also, you suppress any errors that might occur from the `fopen` call, and you don't handle the case where `$handle` is invalid. Those might be error cases that you need to trap.

Comment: Yep - just checked it for sure and `$files` does seem to get what I need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one potential issue with the `scandir()` line:

```
$files = scandir('/../DirectoryToScan');
```

The path begins with a `/`, which means that it is looking in the root of the server. So, the directory it's trying to read is `/DirectoryToScan`. To fix it, you can just remove the leading `/`. Of course, this could be a sample path for this example and may not actually apply to reality, or maybe you really do have a directory in the root of your system named that - in these cases, feel free to ignore this bit =P.

The next thing is when you're using `fopen()` on the files you're iterating through. `scandir()` returns the *name* of the file, not the full path. You'll need to concat the directory name and the file each time:

```
$dir = '../DirectoryToScan/';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file) {
    $handle = @fopen($dir . $file, "r");
```

I'm currently running an older version of PHP, so directly-accessing array indexes from return-functions, such as with `explode("/", $data[0])[1]`, doesn't work for me (it was added in [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-87)).

Other than that, the rest of your code looks like it should work fine (minus any potential logic/data errors that I may have overlooked).

Comment: Ah -- concatenating the directory name onto the file name by modifying my code just like your example solved my problem! Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: @JToland No problem at all, glad I could help!